# Form with two different nested models which exclude each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for one model with a couple of input boxes and one dropdown box where type (`TypeA` and `TypeB`) of the model can be picked. Let's say models are something like this:

```
// car has columns name and country
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
end

// has columns a_property_1 and a_property2
class TypeAProperties < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cars
end

// has columns b_property_1 and b_property2
class TypeBProperties < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cars
end
```

After user opens form, by default there should be displayed fields for name, country, dropdown box with `TypeA` selected, a_property_1 and a_property2.

If user navigates to dropdown box and selects `TypeB`, a_property_1 and a_property2 should disappear from screen, and b_property_1 and b_property2 should appear on screen. So, TypeAProperties and TypeBProperties are created depending on selected value from drop down box. Car can have only one property, A or B.

Any ideas how to handle this situation? I am a little bit stuck with this. Thank you.

Comment: do you need to just show a common form for the that two specific models?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, I need to show a form with input fields for `Car` AND input fields for (`TypeAProperties` OR `TypeBProperties`). I am not sure how to create only Car and TypeBProperties if option B is selected and ignore TypeBProperties.

Comment: where do you select B option?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, I was thinking inside a form so I am not sure should I create a new column inside `Car` to hold type. Form would go something like this: |car input fields| ->  |dropdown for choosing a type| -> |TypeAProperties OR TypeBProperties input fields|  -> |Submit Button|

Comment: i believe you should do vise versa: in `Cars: belongs_to type, polimorphic`, and in  `Type has_one :car`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should do vise versa, so:

```
class Cars < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :car_type, polymorphic: true
end
```

and in type classes

```
class TypeAPropertySet < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :car, as: :car_type # or has_many
end

class TypeBPropertySet < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :car, as: :car_type # or has_many
end
```

Please refer to the [document](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/understanding-polymorphic-associations-in-rails) on the rails polymorphism. So then you be able to use `Car`s properties, along with the `car_type` in the form.